# Not able to set Hand cursor when the mouse cursor is over a button in my MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, cursor

I created a new custom button class (derived from CButton). Overrode the OnMouseMove API in the new custom class. When my mouse cursor moves over the button in a dialog, the OnMouseMove API in the custom button class is called successfully but the cursor symbol is not changed to Hand symbol :(

In the OnMouseMove() API I have the following code:

```
if (m_hClickCursor == NULL) 
    m_hClickCursor = AfxGetApp()->LoadCursor(IDC_CLICK_CURSOR);
if (m_hClickCursor) 
    this->SetCursor(m_hClickCursor);
```

Here,
**IDC_CLICK_CURSOR** is a reference to hand cursor (I use the same hand cursor at other places in my app). 
**m_hClickCursor** is the handle to the cursor

Please Help !!

Thanks,
-Nayan

Comment: Why don't you use a *MFC Button Control*? You just need to define its cursor type has *Hand* in the Resource editor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the [WM_SETCURSOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do this.

Comment: patriiice.. it does not work even after I handled WM_SETCURSOR. The arrow icon of the cursor do not get changed to hand icon when the cursor is moved over the button. But the API gets called successfully.

Comment: do you return TRUE to the WM_SETCURSOR message handler?

Comment: YES, I do return TRUE from the handler.